# How to not match substrings with regex

Tags: python, regex

String to match:

```
{abc}
```

Strings to not match:

```
$${abc{abc}{abc}}$$
```

---

How do I satisfy this requirement with regex?
The context is trying to match `{abc}` elements for replacement with Python, but I don't want them mixed up with [MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/mathematics.html#:%7E:text=%24%24x%20%3D%20%7B%2Db%20%5Cpm%20%5Csqrt%7Bb%5E2%2D4ac%7D%20%5Cover%202a%7D.%24%24) equations `$${abc{abc}{abc}}$$` in a `HTML` file.

I understand `[^$]{.+}` will work somewhat for strings such as `"$${}$$"`, but not others with nested brackets (with content inside nested brackets) such as `"$${{abc}}$$"`. Which shouldn't be matched.

My HTML file looks like this:

```
abc abc {element 1} abc abc {element 2} abc
{element_abc} abc abc

$${abc{abc}{abc}}$$ {element_3} abc abc $${mathjax{}{mathjax}}$$
abc $${mathjax{}{}{}{}{{{mathjax}}}}$$ abc abc
```

Expected results

```html
Match:
{element 1}
{element 2}
{element_abc}
```

```html
Don't match:
$${abc{abc}{abc}}$$
$${mathjax{}{mathjax}}$$
$${mathjax{}{}{}{}{{{mathjax}}}}$$
```

---

- The search doesn't need to scan recursively for intermixed elements:
- `{$${}$$}` can match (not possible in my actual text, so a match can be made if necessary)
- A line of a `{abc}` and a `$${abc}$$` such as `{abc} abc $${abc}$$` may be possible
- Each example is over one line only. E.g. `{element 1}` not `{element\n 1}`

  - So each search can be an anchored search, with consideration to `{abc} abc $${abc}$$`

---

Using `regex 2021.11.10` via `pip`

Comment: Can you `pip install regex` and use this PyPi library? Then it is possible with a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what re expression do I use though?

Comment: `re` does not allow recursion, so there is none for `re`. Only for `regex`.

Comment: What regex expression would work with this sample?

Comment: Regular expressions do not work by themselves. They are plain texts that are parsed by a specific regex engine. You must explicitly state which one you are using.

Comment: Yep, I'll update the question

Comment: Your examples all look like single lines, are you simply looking for an anchored search or something more advanced where you can process basically free-form text which could contain any number of either type of match intermixed with other text?

Comment: I'll update the question once more, but the search is not intermixed or free form

Comment: @tripleee sorry, I though you meant the form `{$${}$$}` by "intermixed", not single lines. My bad

Comment: So it's still not clear what you _actually_ want. Wiktor's solution is probably severe overkill if your requirements are simpler than the most general possible interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PyPi regex library, you can use a SKIP-FAIL recursion-based regex like

```
\$\$({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})\$\$(*SKIP)(*F)|{([^{}]*)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcFbPk/1). *Details*:

- `\$\$({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})\$\$(*SKIP)(*F)`:

  - `\$\$` - a `$$` string
  - `({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})` - Group 1: a `{`, then any zero or more occurrences of any one or more chars other than `{` and `}}` or the same Group 1 pattern recursed, and then `}`
  - `\$\$` - a `$$` string
  - `(*SKIP)(*F)` - "forget" the text matched up to this moment
- `|` - or
- `{([^{}]*)}` - `{`, then Group 2 capturing any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`, and then a `}`.

In Python, you can use

```py
import regex
text = '{element 1}  {element 2} {element_abc} $${abc{abc}{abc}}$$ $${mathjax{}{mathjax}}$$ $${mathjax{}{}{}{}{{{mathjax}}}}$$'
pattern = regex.compile( r'\$\$({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})\$\$(*SKIP)(*F)|{([^{}]*)}' )
print( [match.group() for match in pattern.finditer(text)] )
# => ['{element 1}', '{element 2}', '{element_abc}']
print( [match.group(2) for match in pattern.finditer(text)] )
# => ['element 1', 'element 2', 'element_abc']
```

See [this online demo](https://tio.run/##jVBNa8MwDL3nV@hgiJRCoO1tMHorlF0GO/ZjpJnbuDS2MRqkuPrtWeJ23WEMhpD0pPeEhPyFG2fnfW9a7wJD0EfdZaw7hmfIoz7rVluGqQA8ipk88Hu1rwWUikMeXVIQpcZeW3Fzqroo3@g3cbP4IxgleeYrZh3scEK6p6xd681ZI4R8ozYKIy6e1rso28nkiospUSGUiOLtZfVKWCzpGjEpCpIcKPPBWEZYD4vqpjwG9@mR4OACpA4YC/el5cHYDzMgHL9A2z@GZ/@d7vsv).

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to match the expressions on individual lines, all you need is to add line anchors.

```
^\{[^{}]+\}$
```

If your input is a single string with multiple lines in it, you'll need to add the `re.MULTILINE` flag to say that `^` and `$` should match at internal newlines, too.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'^\{[^{}]+\}$', '''
... {foo}
... $${bar{baz}}
... {quux}
... ick
... ''', re.MULTILINE)
['{foo}', '{quux}']
```

This is portable back to the standard Python `re` module, too.